# How can I disable the buggy "Chrome media router" (Chromecast) extension on a Chromebox using a CLI?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromecast, chromebox

We have a rack of 50 individual Chromeboxes running headless (in kiosk mode). A Chrome update came out in the past few weeks, and ever since then, all these things have been constantly going down after several hours. The screen turns white with the Aw Snap! error. In the logs we've determined that the inbuilt "Chrome Media Router" extension for Chromecast is the culprit. It keeps crashing and taking down the entire process.

We do not want Chromecast running on these devices at all, for a huge number of reasons, but Google is very aggressive about firing it up whether you want to use it or not. There are smart TVs throughout the building that also offer no way to turn it off. So Chromecast has always been a scourge for us, but with all the system crashes it's now wreaking havoc on a daily basis.

Chromecast can be disabled in Chrome using the chrome://flags page, but it requires a UI. We only have CLI access to these boxes, and there is no command line switch for turning this stupid thing off. Supposedly you can set a policy file somewhere but this is undocumented for ChromeOS.